# json.net deserializing - how to specify converters for child objects in the graph?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to work through deserializing using json.net an object with a few children.

I have a custom converter to convert Duty which inherits from BaseDuty class with it's Tasks, which works fine when called with

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<Duty>(json, new CustomJsonConverter());
```

However, when calling

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(json,new CustomJsonConverter());
```

the custom json converter's CanConvert does fire...but doesn't validate as it would when called on against the class it was written for. And what ends up happening is it keeps converting to the base class, which is not what i want to do as the converter correctly converts it.

So, my question is what's the best way to specify the converters for child objects in a graph like below?

Below is an example:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Occupation> Occupations { get;set;}

        public virtual IList<RandomProperty> RandomProperties {get;set;}
    }

    public class Occupation
    {
        public IList<Duty> Duties {get;set;}
    }

public class Duty : BaseDuty
{
   public IList<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}

public class BaseDuty
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about using [JsonConverterAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) to annotate Duty class - for example,

```
[JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))]
public class Duty : BaseDuty
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: i gave this a try, though it didn't quite work. Thanks for something to try though. Ended up writing custom json converters for each in the graph, essentially deserializing it all myself